# Capital Letters and numbers that don't return themselves

Tags: c#, regex

I want to write a regular expression that will accept all the words that follow this rules:

1. The word will only contain capital letters and numbers;
2. The numbers will always be after the letters;
3. There will be an even pairs of capital letters followed by a number;
4. A digit can only appear once in the word.

These are "good" words:

```
T3L9A8L4
A1B2
Q2W4E6R8A1B3D5F7
```

These are "bad" words:

```
T3
TT33
Y3Y4Y6
T1A2B3T1
```

How do I write the regex for this?
Sorry for not adding any code - don't know how to start writing it.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What's the regex you've written so far matching? People will be more likely to help if you show some effort rather than ask for someone to do your work for you.

Comment: Why do you need Regex? A simple function can do it also (in a more readable way).

Comment: If I can do it in loop or inside a method why shouldn't I do it using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use a negative lookahead to prevent repeated numbers and a backreference?

```
^(?!.*(\d).*\1)(?:(?:[A-Z]\d){2})+$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That's the negative lookahead. A number is captured and the match is negated if that number appears again.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/rZ2kB5)

Answer (score 1):

regex can meet your first 3 points,

```
([A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d)+
```

http://rubular.com/r/GXB4BGKQFT

but It can't(practically) meet the last one

> A number can only appear once in the word

In order to accomplish that, you would have to have a different case for every possible permutation of digits, which would be about **10!** cases

Comment: Please see my last edit...